client establishes socket connection with server but there's no print
I am having this python server,
import socket

def server_program():
    # get the hostname
    host = 'localhost' # socket.gethostname()
    port = 8091  # initiate port no above 1024

    server_socket = socket.socket()  # get instance
    # look closely. The bind() function takes tuple as argument
    server_socket.bind((host, port))  # bind host address and port together

    # configure how many client the server can listen simultaneously
    server_socket.listen(2)
    conn, address = server_socket.accept()  # accept new connection
    print("Connection from: " + str(address))
    while True:
        # receive data stream. it won't accept data packet greater than 1024 bytes
        data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
        if not data:
            # if data is not received break
            break
        print("from connected user: " + str(data))
        data = input(' -> ')
        conn.send(data.encode())  # send data to the client

    conn.close()  # close the connection


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_program()

that works with this python client,
import socket

clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect(('localhost', 8091))
clientsocket.send('hello'.encode())

but does not with this ktor client,
fun send() {
    runBlocking {
        val selectorManager = SelectorManager(Dispatchers.IO)
        val socket = aSocket(selectorManager).tcp().connect("10.0.2.2", 8091)

        val receiveChannel = socket.openReadChannel()
        val sendChannel = socket.openWriteChannel(autoFlush = true)


        val myMessage =   "this"  // readln()
        sendChannel.writeStringUtf8("$myMessage\n")   // ("$args\n")
    }
}

The connection is established but there's no print of the string.
It might be very basic but the ktor documentation says little.
With the python client:
Connection from: ('127.0.0.1', 54012)  
from connected user: hello`

With ktor client:
Connection from: ('127.0.0.1', 53334) 


Solved it with
import java.net.Socket


suspend fun sendStuff_() 
{
    val message = "text"
    val socket = Socket("10.0.2.2", 8091)

    socket.outputStream.write(message.toByteArray())
    
}

